# How can I add background color to innerRadius of a donut chart in Recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm  trying to add a background color to innerRadius in donut chart and customize the Cell too. I'm using rechart. This is what I've done[image]

This is what I need it to look like. Sorry it's abit blurry.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import { PieChart, Pie, Cell, Label } from 'recharts';

const data = [
  { name: 'Completed', value: 67 },
  { name: 'Approved', value: 10 },
  // { name: 'Cancelled', value: 46 },
  // { name: 'Pending', value: 67 },
];

export default function Cancelled({COLORS}) {

    return (
      <div>
        <PieChart fill="teal" width={300} height={200}>
        <Pie
        data={data}
        cx="30%"
        cy="50%"
        dataKey="value"
        innerRadius={70}
        outerRadius={80}
        fill="#8884d8"
        >
          {data.map((entry,index)=>{
            if(index===1){
              return <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill="#f3f6f9" />
            }return <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill="green" />
          })}
          <Label
          value={data[0].value}
          position="center"
          fill='black'
          style={{
            fontSize:"32px",
            fontWeight:"normal",
            fontFamily:"Roboto",
            
          }}
          
          />
        </Pie>
        
      </PieChart>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { PieChart, Pie, Cell, Label } from 'recharts';

const data = [
  { name: 'Completed', value: 67 },
  { name: 'Approved', value: 10 },
  // { name: 'Cancelled', value: 46 },
  // { name: 'Pending', value: 67 },
];

const Cancelled = () => (
  <div>
    <PieChart fill="teal" width={300} height={200}>
      <Pie
        data={data}
        dataKey="value"
        innerRadius={70}
        outerRadius={80}
        fill="#8884d8"
      >
        {data.map((entry,index) => {
          if (index === 1) {
            return <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill="white" />
          }
          return <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill="green" />
        })}
      </Pie>
      <Pie
        data={data}
        dataKey="value"
        innerRadius={0}
        outerRadius={70}
        isAnimationActive={false}
      >
        {data.map((entry,index) => {
          return <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill="lightgreen" stroke="lightgreen" />
        })}
        <Label
          value={`${data[0].value}%`}
          position="center"
          fill='black'
          style={{
            fontSize:"32px",
            fontWeight:"normal",
            fontFamily:"Roboto",
          }}
        />
      </Pie>
    </PieChart>
  </div>
);

export default Cancelled
```